# Adding additional classes to the Gutenberg block wrapper in editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

This code should be able to add additional classes block wrapper element based on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324091/add-classname-to-gutenberg-block-wrapper-in-the-editor

However, it doesn't, any help would be much appreciated

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;

const withCustomClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
  return (props) => {
    if (props.name !== 'core/heading') return <BlockListBlock {...props} />

    const { attributes } = props
    return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ "custom-classes-" + attributes.fontSizeChoice } />
  };
}, 'withCustomClassName');

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'custom-name/heading-with-custom-class-name', withCustomClassName );
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an older version of Gutenburg, the latest version 9+ allows this code to work as intended.